# JPA: How to update grandchild entities when updating grandfather entity?

Tags: java, jpa, sql-update, entity, persistence

I've created tables to store information from parsing xml files that are very nested. Therefore the tables in my database are nested too. The top level entity is called SpecimenTb.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SPECIMEN_TB")
public class SpecimenTb implements Serializable {
    private String mrn;
    @Column(name="SPECIMEN_NO", unique = true)
    private String specimenNo;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="specimenTb", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FmReportTb> fmReportTbs;
}
```

SpecimenTb has a child entity called FmReportTb which has its own onetomany relationship to FmReportGeneTb

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FM_REPORT_TB")
public class FmReportTb implements Serializable {
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SpecimenTb
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SPECIMEN_ID")
    private SpecimenTb specimenTb;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="fmReportTb", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FmReportGeneTb> fmReportGeneTbs;
}
```

It is possible a newer version of file will come at a later time, so I need to implement update scheme in my code. When I persist, I look for record in SpecimenTb by specimenNo. If it does not exist, insert new record. Otherwise, update the same records, father, children and grandkids.

```
    SpecimenDao specimenDao = new SpecimenDao(em);
    SpecimenTb specimenTb = specimenDao.findSpecimenBySpecno(blockId);
    FmReportTb report = null;
    if (specimenTb != null) { // update
        report = specimenTb.getFmReportTbs().get(0);
    } else { // insert
        report = new FmReportTb();
    }
    if (report.getFmReportGeneTbs() != null) { // update
        geneList = report.getFmReportGeneTbs();
        geneList.clear();
    } else { //insert
        geneList = new ArrayList<FmReportGeneTb>();
    }
    // parse "Genes" section of xml and store in geneList
    for (Node gene : genes) {
        FmReportGeneTb geneTb = new FmReportGeneTb();
        << set a bunch of stuff for geneTb>>
        geneTb.setFmReportTb(report);
    }
    geneList.add(geneTb);
    report.setFmReportGeneTb(geneList);
    if (specimenTb == null) { // insert new record
        specimenTb = new SpecimenTb();
        specimenTb.setSpecimenNo(blockId);
        specimenTb.setMrn(mrn);
        report.setSpecimenTb(specimenTb);
        reports.add(report);
        specimenTb.setFmReportTbs(reports);
        specimenDao.persistSpecimen(specimenTb);
    } else { // update
        report.setSpecimenTb(specimenTb);
        reports.add(report);
        specimenDao.updateSpecimen(specimenTb, mrn, reports);
    }
```

In the DAO class, persist and update methods are as follows:
// insert

```
public void persistSpecimen(SpecimenTb specimen) {
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.persist(specimen);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

// update

```
public void updateSpecimen(SpecimenTb specimen, String mrn, List<FmReportTb> reports) {
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction(); 
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        specimen.setSpecimenNo(blockId);
        specimen.setMrn(mrn);
        specimen.setFmReportTbs(reports);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

Insert works exactly what I wanted, it persists father entity and all entities underneath thanks to `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`. When I update though, it does update the old record in SpecimenTb and FmReportTb but tends to insert a new series of records in FmReportGeneTb. So I ended up appending a new set of records in FmReportGeneTb that is linked to the same FmReportTb instead of updating (GeneList in old and new versions may differ in length). There are actually child entities and grandchild entities of FmReportGeneTb that I did not show. How do I update all related tables from top down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what other fields do you set on `FmReportTb`, but seen your code, on the first line there is a

`FmReportTb report = new FmReportTb();`

That explain why you ended having two records of `FmReportTb` in your specimen.
If you want to update the existing `FmReportTb` you should set its id before update it.

Comment: I edited my post my modifying ways to set FmReportTb. Now it is updating FmReportTb instead of inserting. But there is a child entity of FmReportTb called FmReportGeneTb I need to update too. Since it is a list, it is not really update at genetb level but rather delete old list of records and insert new ones. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: if you are using hibernate, try putting an additional [@Cascade({DELETE_ORPHAN})](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#DELETE_ORPHAN) on fmReportGeneTbs (this cascade is from hibernate).

Comment: I am using JPA 2.1. Should I do `orphanRemoval=true` instead?

Comment: since I am removing the whole geneTb list, can I just `clear()` the list instead of iterating the list, remove every one of them and nullify parent as well?

Comment: with 'orphanRemoval=true' on the list of fmReportGeneTbs you can just clear your list and add new ones. You don't need to nullify each parent.

Comment: I ran two transactions in the update method. First to clear all child entities. Second to update all children. Both committed. However, both old and new list of genes are found in FmReportTb. I tested clear method by itself and was able to clear entity list. Why am I still appending new list to the old list?

Comment: Are you calling `merge` or `persist` from `entityManager` on your update? Even if the instance is connected, you need to call one of these methods for the cascade work.

Comment: I didn't call either. I call persist when I insert new records. For updates, I just set a bunch of stuff and commit. Should I call merge or persist for updates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117428/discussion-between-hashicode-and-ddd).